# Calling Malloc from Within a Wrapper Macro

Tags: c, macros, malloc, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a few macros to debug some code I am working on, but I have run into an issue, and I am not sure how to resolve it. I would like to wrap malloc with another function, then use a macro to replace any calls with the wrapper. The issue is that the wrapper itself must call malloc. I have a header file like this:

memory.h:

```
#define malloc(X) my_malloc( X, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__ )
#define free(X) my_free( X )

void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char*func);
void my_free(void *ptr);
```

Then I have an associated .c file to define the wrapper functions.

memory.c:

```
#include "memory.h"
void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char*func) {
    void *ptr = malloc(size);
    /* do stuff */
    return ptr;
}

void my_free(void *ptr) {
    /* do stuff */
    free(ptr);
}
```

Finally, I have the code where I want the macros to work.

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int *my_ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) );
    free(my_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue that I run into is that the function becomes recursive and crashes the program. My question is, is there a way that I can keep my implementation separate from my header file, and still get access to the real malloc function from within that (i.e. so the .c file knows to call the correct malloc instead of the preprocessor replacing it)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Split the header up, such that the macro is not defined in `memory.c` (but everything else still is).

Comment: Oh, good idea! So effectively, on header for the source code, and another defining the macros, which includes the source code header?

Comment: What about putting `my_malloc` in a separate source file that does not include the macro?  Otherwise, you could probably get away with using `#undef` in your `memory.c`, though it's not exactly pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this, is to `#undef` `malloc` and `free` macros in `memory.c`:

memory.c:

```
#undef malloc
#undef free

void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char*func)
{
    ...
}
...
void my_free(void *ptr)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Another way, is to declare `my_malloc` and `my_free` functions as `extern`. In this way the `memory.h` which contains `malloc` and `free` should not be included in `memory.c`.

memory.c:

```
/* #include "memory.h" */

extern void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char*func)
{
    ...
}
...
extern void my_free(void *ptr)
{
    ...
}
```

memory.h

```
extern void *my_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char*func);
...
extern void my_free(void *ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!